# Does Drupal comply with the MVC paradigm?

Tags: model-view-controller, drupal

Drupal is frequently referred as a Content Management Framework, does it comply with the MVC paradigm? If it does, how Drupal implements MVC?

Thanks.

Comment: you can however develope using mvc architecture in drupal, but the system it self does not

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, Drupal follows the PAC ([Presentation-Abstraction-Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control)) model rather than MVC. There is an excellent blog post explaining this at [Larry Garfield's site](http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/mvc-vs-pac).

Answer (score 7):

Drupal 8 now incorporates [Symfony](https://symfony.com) components. So this means while a Drupal 8 application is not an MVC framework/CMS as a whole, Drupal 8 modules are implemented in an MVC pattern with controllers, routes and Twig templates for Views.

Comment: Yes, Drupal 8 uses Twig, a Symfony project, but everything using Twig--not just modules but the theming engine of Drupal core too--uses some amount of MVC in Drupal 8. Here are more authoritative links: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig
https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html

Comment: Edit: Please ignore the first part of my previous comment, since Drupal core offloads to the theming engine and thus doesn't include the MVC pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No it does not.
You can however develop software using mvc architecture and there are even modules to facilitate that, but the system it self does not. maby it will in the future.

but some fundamental concepts of drupal, like the hooks, are conflicting with the mvc paradigm

Answer (score 2):

No, drupal is not an MVC framework at all.